# Set expiry time to a file while downloading

Tags: html, file, file-properties

Is it possible to set Expiry time for a file while downloading from an URL. We have set expiry for the URL but we don’t have control on the file post download.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the availability of a file do not provide the real url for downloading it.
Use simple proxy code on your backend, and javascript for the frontend to tell the user that the file is not available without reload.

Comment: We are already adding a expiry time for the Download URL , But will it be possible to add expiry time for the file while downloading. So that the file will be deleted once it reaches expiryTime and user cant access it even if it is downloaded already in the user machine

Comment: Are you meaning to delete the file offline? No chance. If it's video or music, streaming is used to gain control.

Comment: Basically not to allow users to open / view it